# No RTP engine was found. Do you have one loaded? Asterisk-18.10.1

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk, voip, sip, rtp

I have been trying to install Asterisk-18.10.1 version on my ubuntu(20.04.4) running inside VM. I was able to maintain connection from GoTrunk SIP endpoint and Zoiper as softphone. Followed https://github.com/GoTrunk/asterisk-config/tree/dynamic-ip tutorial mostly. When I try to call from Zoiper, I got the following error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g4VT.png)
I tried module show like rtp , module show like res_rtp_asterisk.so, and module load res_rtp_asterisk.so on Asterisk CLI but couldnot see any of such modules. I checked menuselect, but necessary menus were selected as suggested on previous issues. I also tried: https://www.asterisk.org/asterisk-16-has-a-new-module-loader/
[tried module loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj5gr.png)
BUT no progess so far. Would appreciate your direction and any help.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the module is actually built:

```
file /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/res_rtp_asterisk.so
/usr/lib/asterisk/modules/res_rtp_asterisk.so: LSB shared object, Intel ... dynamically linked
```